# C++: Can I save a rand() generator to an object for asynchronous determinism?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, random

I've searched around but struggled to find something that exactly fits my needs. I want to generate a series of random numbers with rand() after setting the seed with srand().

The catch is I need to do this asynchronously and other random sequences may be concurrently generated. I need to maintain the same deterministic sequence that would be generated all at once. Because rand() is global, I don't think there's any way to do this with rand().

The solution in my mind would be something that acts just like srand/rand but can be saved and passed as an object. e.g.

`RandGenerator random(srand_seed)
int r = random.get_random();`

I don't need any of the "extra random" utils from C++11, but I'll use them if they somehow help me here. I just don't understand where to look.

Comment: `I don't need any of the "extra random" utils from C++11` Your example of what the solution in your minds looks like is exactly what C++11 random does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't need any of the "extra random" utils from C++11

Well, according to your problem, C++11 random is exactly what you need. It even look like your small solution in your mind.

This is an example inspired from [`cppreference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random):

```
#include <random>

int main()
{
    // Use the default random engine.
    // Thread local for thread safety, and to not recreate that large object.
    thread_local std::default_random_engine rnd(std::random_device{}());

    // A a uniform distribution of 1 to 6, like a dice
    // It does not have the random state, but only the distribution the numbers should have.
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 6);

    // Generate a random number using a distribution and the random engine.
    int randomNumber = uniform_dist(rnd); // from 1 to 6
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! One more question sorry - how can I seed a random engine like this? I looked over the docs but I don't see an equivalent input to `srand` (may have missed something).

Comment: @BenWiley see the linked cppreference link. It explains it all. The example I've written there is practically stolen from cppreference. In the code I showed you, the random engine is seeded using a random physical device.

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumeRacicot - I think I understand. Sorry if my questions sound naive, I still feel very new to C++. So I guess when the distribution is initialized it will retain the random engine in use at the time of initialization even if I set another random engine and create another new distribution in the same thread?

Comment: I'm sorry that was a dumb question. I just realized we're passing the random engine into the distribution. I'm too used to magic globals in C.... Thank you!

Comment: @BenWiley not exactly. The random engine has all the state required to generate random number. The random engine is the thing you want to use in a thread safe manner. The distribution however don't have any state related to the random numbers. A distribution is really lightweight and there is nothing wrong to have a distribution as local object. The distribution will simply apply the generated random number to the desired distribution using fancy maths. The operation `uniform_dist(rnd)` is (very) roughtly equivalent to `1+ (rand() % 6)` in that particular case.

Comment: @BenWiley In this example, I used `thread_local` Because I want the random engine to be global since they are usually heavy, but I want tohave one of those global by thread to not run into race condition. This is what thread local does.

Comment: I guess I don't understand then, and I'm not sure this will work for me. I only plan to use a single thread but I want to have maybe 9 or 12 or 15 different random engines going concurrently and I want them to produce deterministic sequences (the application is seed based population of game tiles that need to load progressively across multiple frames). Is there something wrong with using multiple random engines over time?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. Since you're not doing multithreading, you can use the same engine for your multiple sequences, and you can use multiple engines too. However, I would suggest avoiding moving them around because they are heavy objects.